# Linksys (WRT54GL) Remote Management switched off but still accessible

Tags: router

I've just updated my firmware on my linksys (now Firmware Version: v4.30.14) and I have a strange bug. I've always disabled my remote access feature for security reasons. but with this new firmware i've still got the Remote Router Access option disabled but it seems I can still access it through my external ip (http://82.xx.xx.243).

Anyone else have this problem with this router?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it's probably not accessible from an alien network. The router might detect that you are trying to access it from within your network, since you're making a request to your own IP. Try accessing it from another internet connection.